# Capistrano 3.5 deploy error 'database.yml' no such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

Problems deploying to server since upgrading to Rails 4.2.6, Capistrano 3.5 and Ruby 2.3.1

It was fine with Rails 4.2.3, Capistrano 3.4 and Ruby 2.3.0.

It's failing on deleting database.yml and won't proceed with the linked files.

Capistrano nor deploy files have been changed.

### Capistrano log:

```
DEBUG [d2eceac4] Command: [ -L /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503132540/config/database.yml ]
 DEBUG [d23f79fc] Finished in 0.505 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [8250d094] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503132540/config/database.yml ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [8250d094] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503132540/config/database.yml ]
 DEBUG [d2eceac4] Finished in 0.504 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [57a5da20] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503132540/config/database.yml ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [57a5da20] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503132540/config/database.yml ]
 DEBUG [8250d094] Finished in 0.497 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [57de892b] Running /usr/bin/env rm /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503132540/config/database.yml as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [57de892b] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env rm /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503132540/config/database.yml )
 DEBUG [57a5da20] Finished in 0.498 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [db9b565c] Running /usr/bin/env rm /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503132540/config/database.yml as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [db9b565c] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env rm /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503132540/config/database.yml )
 DEBUG [57de892b]   rm: 
 DEBUG [57de892b]   cannot remove ‘/apps/rails.app/releases/20160503132540/config/database.yml’
  INFO [db9b565c] Finished in 0.504 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [57de892b]   : No such file or directory
  INFO [3aaa1aef] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /apps/rails.app/shared/config/database.yml /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503132540/config/database.yml as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [57de892b]   
 DEBUG [3aaa1aef] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /apps/rails.app/shared/config/database.yml /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503132540/config/database.yml )
```

### The Capistrano 'deploy.rb' file:

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.5.0'

set :application, 'rails.app'
set :repo_url, 'git@internal-address:user/rails-app.git'

# Passenger
set :passenger_restart_with_touch, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'config/initializers/devise.rb', 'config/environments/production.rb')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads')

namespace :deploy do
  after :publishing, :restart
  after :finishing, :cleanup
end
```

I'm not sure what how else to debug. It looks like :linked_files aren't working at all.

Any help is much appreciated.

### Updated Capistrano log with airbursh

```
 DEBUG [7bbcb734] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env chmod +rx /tmp/rails.app/git-ssh.sh )
  INFO [2e25ebb3] Finished in 0.508 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [7bbcb734] Finished in 0.511 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [24e11804] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@internal-address:user/rails-app.git as deploy@10.1.1.1
  INFO [835e01c4] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@internal-address:user/rails-app.git as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [24e11804] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/rails.app/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@internal-address:user/rails-app.git )
 DEBUG [835e01c4] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/rails.app/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@internal-address:user/rails-app.git )
 DEBUG [835e01c4]   6c44e0217160f77f5ad6e4f0a49d7b6d61d5a585    refs/heads/master
  INFO [835e01c4] Finished in 1.619 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [24e11804]   6c44e0217160f77f5ad6e4f0a49d7b6d61d5a585    refs/heads/master
  INFO [24e11804] Finished in 1.724 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [108ed63b] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/shared /apps/rails.app/releases as deploy@10.1.1.1
  INFO [4fb82c3f] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/shared /apps/rails.app/releases as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [108ed63b] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/shared /apps/rails.app/releases )
 DEBUG [4fb82c3f] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/shared /apps/rails.app/releases )
  INFO [108ed63b] Finished in 0.511 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [4fb82c3f] Finished in 0.533 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [81721186] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/shared/log /apps/rails.app/shared/tmp/pids /apps/rails.app/shared/tmp/cache /apps/rails.app/shared/tmp/sockets /apps/rails.app/shared/vendor/bundle /apps/rails.app/shared/public/system /apps/rails.app/shared/public/uploads /apps/rails.app/shared/public/spree /apps/rails.app/shared/public/assets as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [81721186] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/shared/log /apps/rails.app/shared/tmp/pids /apps/rails.app/shared/tmp/cache /apps/rails.app/shared/tmp/sockets /apps/rails.app/shared/vendor/bundle /apps/rails.app/shared/public/system /apps/rails.app/shared/public/uploads /apps/rails.app/shared/public/spree /apps/rails.app/shared/public/assets )
  INFO [6222351d] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/shared/log /apps/rails.app/shared/tmp/pids /apps/rails.app/shared/tmp/cache /apps/rails.app/shared/tmp/sockets /apps/rails.app/shared/vendor/bundle /apps/rails.app/shared/public/system /apps/rails.app/shared/public/uploads /apps/rails.app/shared/public/spree /apps/rails.app/shared/public/assets as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [6222351d] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/shared/log /apps/rails.app/shared/tmp/pids /apps/rails.app/shared/tmp/cache /apps/rails.app/shared/tmp/sockets /apps/rails.app/shared/vendor/bundle /apps/rails.app/shared/public/system /apps/rails.app/shared/public/uploads /apps/rails.app/shared/public/spree /apps/rails.app/shared/public/assets )
  INFO [81721186] Finished in 0.511 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [6222351d] Finished in 0.517 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [e938c2ed] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/shared/config /apps/rails.app/shared/config/initializers /apps/rails.app/shared/config/environments as deploy@10.1.1.1
  INFO [8b269541] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/shared/config /apps/rails.app/shared/config/initializers /apps/rails.app/shared/config/environments as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [e938c2ed] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/shared/config /apps/rails.app/shared/config/initializers /apps/rails.app/shared/config/environments )
 DEBUG [8b269541] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/shared/config /apps/rails.app/shared/config/initializers /apps/rails.app/shared/config/environments )
  INFO [8b269541] Finished in 0.511 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [e938c2ed] Finished in 0.515 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [f343bdfd] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/database.yml ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [f343bdfd] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/database.yml ]
 DEBUG [7ffd93cf] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/database.yml ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [7ffd93cf] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/database.yml ]
 DEBUG [f343bdfd] Finished in 0.651 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [7ffd93cf] Finished in 0.651 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [e702218c] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/secrets.yml ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [d818ca0c] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/secrets.yml ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [e702218c] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/secrets.yml ]
 DEBUG [d818ca0c] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/secrets.yml ]
 DEBUG [d818ca0c] Finished in 0.713 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [e702218c] Finished in 0.714 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [12407dd8] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/initializers/devise.rb ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [e3e041ea] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/initializers/devise.rb ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [12407dd8] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/initializers/devise.rb ]
 DEBUG [e3e041ea] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/initializers/devise.rb ]
 DEBUG [e3e041ea] Finished in 0.563 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [4b88667e] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/environments/production.rb ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [4b88667e] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/environments/production.rb ]
 DEBUG [12407dd8] Finished in 0.567 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [198b268c] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/environments/production.rb ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [198b268c] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/shared/config/environments/production.rb ]
 DEBUG [198b268c] Finished in 0.659 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [4b88667e] Finished in 0.663 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [8ed12ce4] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/current/REVISION ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [6197181a] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/current/REVISION ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [8ed12ce4] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/current/REVISION ]
 DEBUG [6197181a] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/current/REVISION ]
 DEBUG [6197181a] Finished in 0.613 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [8ed12ce4] Finished in 0.614 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [6f52d4fe] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/repo/HEAD ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [6f52d4fe] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/repo/HEAD ]
 DEBUG [67b5f166] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/repo/HEAD ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [67b5f166] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/repo/HEAD ]
 DEBUG [67b5f166] Finished in 0.612 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO The repository mirror is at /apps/rails.app/repo
 DEBUG [6f52d4fe] Finished in 0.615 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO The repository mirror is at /apps/rails.app/repo
 DEBUG [2b67785a] Running if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [2b67785a] Command: if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [ae7842b2] Running if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [ae7842b2] Command: if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [ae7842b2] Finished in 0.813 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [2b67785a] Finished in 0.814 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [325867a4] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update --prune as deploy@10.1.1.1
  INFO [281200ea] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update --prune as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [325867a4] Command: cd /apps/rails.app/repo && ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/rails.app/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git remote update --prune )
 DEBUG [281200ea] Command: cd /apps/rails.app/repo && ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/rails.app/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git remote update --prune )
 DEBUG [281200ea]   Fetching origin
 DEBUG [325867a4]   Fetching origin
  INFO [281200ea] Finished in 3.990 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [325867a4] Finished in 4.390 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [b42735e9] Running if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [e3a4323b] Running if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [b42735e9] Command: if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [e3a4323b] Command: if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [e3a4323b] Finished in 0.552 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [455818b5] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321 as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [455818b5] Command: cd /apps/rails.app/repo && ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/rails.app/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321 )
 DEBUG [b42735e9] Finished in 0.663 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [76ad05b3] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321 as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [76ad05b3] Command: cd /apps/rails.app/repo && ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/rails.app/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321 )
  INFO [76ad05b3] Finished in 0.676 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [3dc8fdf0] Running /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -f - -C /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321 as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [3dc8fdf0] Command: cd /apps/rails.app/repo && ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/rails.app/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -f - -C /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321 )
  INFO [455818b5] Finished in 1.094 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [37d6097b] Running /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -f - -C /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321 as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [37d6097b] Command: cd /apps/rails.app/repo && ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/rails.app/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -f - -C /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321 )
  INFO [3dc8fdf0] Finished in 0.676 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [37d6097b] Finished in 0.617 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [c7cb6b36] Running if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [c7cb6b36] Command: if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [d2fc254f] Running if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [d2fc254f] Command: if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [c7cb6b36] Finished in 0.510 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [f36d849c] Running /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 master as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [f36d849c] Command: cd /apps/rails.app/repo && ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/rails.app/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 master )
 DEBUG [d2fc254f] Finished in 0.511 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [66210d4a] Running /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 master as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [66210d4a] Command: cd /apps/rails.app/repo && ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/rails.app/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 master )
 DEBUG [66210d4a]   6c44e0217160f77f5ad6e4f0a49d7b6d61d5a585
 DEBUG [f36d849c]   6c44e0217160f77f5ad6e4f0a49d7b6d61d5a585
 DEBUG [66210d4a] Finished in 0.609 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [f36d849c] Finished in 0.611 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [48152738] Running if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [c75ef954] Running if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321'" 1>&2; false; fi as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [48152738] Command: if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [c75ef954] Command: if test ! -d /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321; then echo "Directory does not exist '/apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321'" 1>&2; false; fi
 DEBUG [c75ef954] Finished in 0.611 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [48152738] Finished in 0.613 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [e92eb11a] Running /usr/bin/env echo "6c44e0217160f77f5ad6e4f0a49d7b6d61d5a585" >> REVISION as deploy@10.1.1.1
  INFO [0b874ecd] Running /usr/bin/env echo "6c44e0217160f77f5ad6e4f0a49d7b6d61d5a585" >> REVISION as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [e92eb11a] Command: cd /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env echo "6c44e0217160f77f5ad6e4f0a49d7b6d61d5a585" >> REVISION )
 DEBUG [0b874ecd] Command: cd /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env echo "6c44e0217160f77f5ad6e4f0a49d7b6d61d5a585" >> REVISION )
  INFO [e92eb11a] Finished in 0.715 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [0b874ecd] Finished in 0.717 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [832806bb] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/initializers /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/environments as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [832806bb] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/initializers /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/environments )
  INFO [e070e685] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/initializers /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/environments as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [e070e685] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/initializers /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/environments )
  INFO [e070e685] Finished in 0.605 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [832806bb] Finished in 0.606 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [4ab4c329] Running [ -L /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/database.yml ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [4ab4c329] Command: [ -L /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/database.yml ]
 DEBUG [767423b2] Running [ -L /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/database.yml ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [767423b2] Command: [ -L /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/database.yml ]
 DEBUG [767423b2] Finished in 0.611 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [4ab4c329] Finished in 0.611 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [97faa711] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/database.yml ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [2c729ebd] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/database.yml ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [97faa711] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/database.yml ]
 DEBUG [2c729ebd] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/database.yml ]
 DEBUG [97faa711] Finished in 0.614 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [e226dd42] Running /usr/bin/env rm /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/database.yml as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [2c729ebd] Finished in 0.614 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [e226dd42] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env rm /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/database.yml )
  INFO [a86cbba8] Running /usr/bin/env rm /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/database.yml as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [a86cbba8] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env rm /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/database.yml )
  INFO [a86cbba8] Finished in 0.613 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [e226dd42]   rm: 
  INFO [5c68a013] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /apps/rails.app/shared/config/database.yml /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/database.yml as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [5c68a013] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /apps/rails.app/shared/config/database.yml /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/database.yml )
 DEBUG [e226dd42]   cannot remove ‘/apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/database.yml’
 DEBUG [e226dd42]   : No such file or directory
 DEBUG [e226dd42]   
  INFO [5c68a013] Finished in 0.609 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [b8d274e0] Running [ -L /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/secrets.yml ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [b8d274e0] Command: [ -L /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/secrets.yml ]
 DEBUG [b8d274e0] Finished in 0.614 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [105bc70e] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/secrets.yml ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [105bc70e] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/secrets.yml ]
 DEBUG [105bc70e] Finished in 0.578 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [adebc866] Running /usr/bin/env rm /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/secrets.yml as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [adebc866] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env rm /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/secrets.yml )
  INFO [adebc866] Finished in 0.600 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [83f09b01] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /apps/rails.app/shared/config/secrets.yml /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/secrets.yml as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [83f09b01] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /apps/rails.app/shared/config/secrets.yml /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/secrets.yml )
  INFO [83f09b01] Finished in 0.512 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [e100031e] Running [ -L /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/initializers/devise.rb ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [e100031e] Command: [ -L /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/initializers/devise.rb ]
 DEBUG [e100031e] Finished in 0.510 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [f5babdc6] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/initializers/devise.rb ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [f5babdc6] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/initializers/devise.rb ]
 DEBUG [f5babdc6] Finished in 0.557 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [e95890a8] Running /usr/bin/env rm /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/initializers/devise.rb as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [e95890a8] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env rm /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/initializers/devise.rb )
  INFO [e95890a8] Finished in 0.773 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [a9e24ee8] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /apps/rails.app/shared/config/initializers/devise.rb /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/initializers/devise.rb as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [a9e24ee8] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /apps/rails.app/shared/config/initializers/devise.rb /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/initializers/devise.rb )
  INFO [a9e24ee8] Finished in 0.615 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [81592677] Running [ -L /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/environments/production.rb ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [81592677] Command: [ -L /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/environments/production.rb ]
 DEBUG [81592677] Finished in 0.507 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 DEBUG [c566939a] Running [ -f /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/environments/production.rb ] as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [c566939a] Command: [ -f /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/environments/production.rb ]
 DEBUG [c566939a] Finished in 0.560 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [ad927d39] Running /usr/bin/env rm /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/environments/production.rb as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [ad927d39] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env rm /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/environments/production.rb )
  INFO [ad927d39] Finished in 0.514 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [660c0bde] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /apps/rails.app/shared/config/environments/production.rb /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/environments/production.rb as deploy@10.1.1.1
 DEBUG [660c0bde] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="/home/deploy/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.1" ; /usr/bin/env ln -s /apps/rails.app/shared/config/environments/production.rb /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503152321/config/environments/production.rb )
  INFO [660c0bde] Finished in 0.610 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

Comment: What about file permission? Does a user running new capistrano has permission to `database.yml` file?

Comment: The permissions hasn't changed. Do I need to give capistrano specific flags for permission? It looks like Capistrano is deleting database.yml but it doesn't exists for some reason. The git repo does have a plain database.yml (which will be replaced with a symlink from shared/config)

Comment: I thought you said the file is there and capistrano can't remove it. Capistrano is probably ssh'ing using your local keys. Can you log into the remote server and do `/apps/rails.app/releases/20160503132540/config/database.yml`?

Comment: Sorry. The shared file is there; but it's missing from /apps/rails.app/releases/20160503132540/config/database.yml which is strange right?

Comment: Hmm.. As a workaround, just add a dummy file there and see if the next deploy goes smoothly.

Comment: Yeah, actually it looks like all linked_files aren't working at all.

Comment: How many servers are you deploying to?

Comment: Just 1 server; It was working fine with Capistrano 3.4.. Trying to figure out what's changed between versions.

Comment: Could you change the formatter to airbrussh and post the output? It is easier to parse.

Comment: @will_in_wi I've updated the description. It looks pretty much the same; I've deploy:clear and it does look like the database.yml is there, it's a symbolic link. The SHKit::Runner::ExecuteError is the same, nothing written; database.yml: No such file or directory.

Comment: @WasabiDeveloper Though it 's a bit late, did you find any solution on this?